# Create synonym dictionary to add instead of replace words in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am building an application where I added a Full Text Search feature using PostgreSQL's built in FTS. The app lists Mutual Funds in India. In some cases, mutual fund companies get acquired and their name changes. I wanted to allow people to search using the old names in case they were not aware of the change. So for instance, when DHFL funds got acquired by PGIM, all funds were renamed from DHFL to PGIM.

To achieve this, I created a synonym dictionary where I added PGIM as a synonym for DHFL.

However, I discovered that this simply replaces DHFL with PGIM. Which means that some older funds, which still retain the name of DHFL, are no longer returned in my query with the word dhfl.

Is there an option where a synonym adds a word rather than replace it, such that DHFL searches for both DHFL and PGIM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the new dictionary both with `to_tsvector` and `to_tsquery`. Then all occurrences of DHFL will be replaced by PGIM in both, and searching for either term will find either string. They will be treated as synonyms, which is what you want.